# how to create a keyspace in cassandra?

Tags: java, eclipse, cassandra, apache-spark

i'm using a snippet to understand cassandra and syntax:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cluster cluster;
        Session session;

        // Connect to the cluster and key space "demo"
        cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
        session = cluster.connect("demo");

        // Insert one record into the users table
        session.execute("INSERT INTO users (lastname, age, city, email, firstname) VALUES ('Jones', 35, 'Austin', 'bob@example.com', 'Bob')");

        // Use select to get the user we just entered
        ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE lastname='Jones'");
        for (Row row : results) {
            System.out.format("%s %d\n", row.getString("firstname"), row.getInt("age"));
        }

        // Update the same user with a new age
        session.execute("update users set age = 36 where lastname = 'Jones'");

        // Select and show the change
        results = session.execute("select * from users where lastname='Jones'");
        for (Row row : results) {
            System.out.format("%s %d\n", row.getString("firstname"), row.getInt("age"));
        }

        // Delete the user from the users table
        session.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE lastname = 'Jones'");

        // Show that the user is gone
        results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM users");
        for (Row row : results) {
            System.out.format("%s %d %s %s %s\n", row.getString("lastname"), row.getInt("age"), row.getString("city"),
                    row.getString("email"), row.getString("firstname"));
        }

        // Clean up the connection by closing it
        cluster.close();
    }
}
```

On execution i get this error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.datastax.driver.core.SystemProperties).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Keyspace 'demo' does not exist
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:289)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:287)
    at org.sparkexamples.cassandraExample.main.App.main(App.java:17)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Keyspace 'demo' does not exist
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:103)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:140)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:293)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:455)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:734)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.java:36)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:294)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In addiction, i configured everything with spark (maven/libs), but i don't know  how to create a keyspace using java code?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have a `session` instance. Use it to issue a create keyspace command:

```
session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS  test WITH replication = {"
  + " 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', "
  + " 'replication_factor': '3' "
  + "};" );
```

the `IF NOT EXISTS` part will prevent the statement from throwing an error in case the keyspace already exists.

Comment: i used your suggestion, but i'm getting the same errors                  `cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
  session = cluster.connect("test");
  session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication "
    + "= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':3};");`

Comment: you should not use `cluster.connect("test")` as the keyspace does not exist yet. Use `session = cluster.connect();` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can create keypsace using CQL statement `CREATE KEYSPACE`. Please refer to this document for details http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_keyspace_r.html

There is no difference between running `SELECT` or `CREATE` statement from java code.

Comment: Sure. Just run it exactly as you are doing with `select`, `delete` or any other statement.

Answer (score 1):

Create keyspace_creation.cql as below:
--> vim keyspace_creation.cql

```
create keyspace demo WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor': 3 };
USE ycsb;
create table usertable (
y_id varchar primary key,
field0 varchar,
field1 varchar,
field2 varchar,
field3 varchar,
field4 varchar,
field5 varchar,
field6 varchar,
field7 varchar,
field8 varchar,
field9 varchar);
```

--> cd $CASSANDRA_HOME/bin
--> ./cqlsh

```
cqlsh> source '~/$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/keyspace_creation.cql';
```